# Speed difference through Google cloud load balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-load-balancer

We have k8s cluster with apps hosted on GKE.
When we are trying to get static content (8.25Mb) through Google cloud load balancer retrieving time is 3.8s, when we are trying do it directly through nginx on our k8s cluster in VM it takes 0.2s. What can be a reason of speed difference? Does Google cloud load balancer have any settings for example for bandwidth?

```
~$ wget https://.../main.js
...
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 8649943 (8.2M) [application/javascript]
Saving to: 'main.js'
main.js               100%[========================================================================================>]   8.25M  2.27MB/s    in 3.8s 


__________________________________

Nginx

~$ wget https://.../main.js
...
Saving to: 'main.js'
main.js               100%[========================================================================================>]   8.25M  50.2MB/s    in 0.2s
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say it is related with **loadbalancer**. Keep in mind that downloading something that is hosted in the cloud will always take considerably more time then something available locally.

If you have such suspition that **loadbalancer** could make a difference, you should rather compare it with the speed when downloading directly from your **GKE** node. You can expose your **nginx** `Deployment` via [`NodePort`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) `Service` and avoid this way using **loadbalancer**. If such download will take much less time than downloading through **loadbalancer** then you could blame the **loadbalancer**. But I'm quite sure that the result will be almost the same.

Where do you have your **local k8s cluster** ? Is it somewhere on your local network ? Or maybe on a **VM** running on the same machine from which you're executing `wget` ? If so, it will **always** take much less time than downloading from any **cloud-hosted VM**.

The network parameters such as **download speed** and **latency** will also depend on what **region** is your **GKE cluster** hosted in. If this is some region which is located quite far away from your location, those parameters can differ quite considerably comparing with the one that is located relatively near to you.